# Decreasing sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$, with $|f_{n}(x)|\leq C, \forall n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)=0$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$, does there exist a subsequence of $\{f_{n}\}$ which is decreasing on $\mathbb R$?

**Edit:** What if $\{\sup_{\mathbb R}|f_{n}(x)|\}$ is also converges to 0, and all $f_{n}$ are positive continuous functions with the above properties?

Comment: $f_n(x) =\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$

Comment: Take for $f_n$ a bump of height $1/n$ and width $1$ centered at $n$.

Comment: Will any type of "bump" work?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Yes. Draw a picture.

Comment: @Adam: And please use the @ thing.

Comment: @Adam: What if $\{\sup_{\mathbb R}|f_{n}(x)|\}$ is also converges to 0, and all $f_{n}$ are positive continuous functions? Does it change the answer?

Comment: The $\sup$ converging to $0$ is the same as uniformly converging to $0$. Modify the example from @N.S. by taking the absolute value. This satisfies your latest criteria.

Comment: did - what is the @ thing?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $f_n(x) \equiv -1/n$. Then $|f_n(x)|\le 1 \  \forall n $, $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformily on $\mathbb{R}$ and All subsequence of $(f_n)$ is  strictly increasing.

Comment: your functions are not bounded (as Mathblue requires)

Comment: It is bounded by one.

Comment: Not bounded?  $|f_n(x)| \le 1/n$.

Comment: oooh yeah I read it as 1/x. My bad